# Can I use the azure webjobs sdk from a nodejs webapp?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobssdk, azure-queues

I have a Azure web-app built using NodeJS and wanted to create a webjob triggered by a queue. Looks like this can be achieved using a QueueTrigger from azure-webjobs-sdk.

I have found examples for

- Defining the webjob in C#
- Using a NodeJS based webjob defined in C#(I think)

Is it possible to define a Webjob using the SDK from NodeJS code?

P.S. I don't want to run a continous webjob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WebJobs SDK is only usable from C# code when writing Azure WebJobs. However, if you use Azure Functions, you get the same functionality as WebJobs for functions written in JavaScript and other languages. You can check out quickstarts and tutorials in the docs [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/)